# How to render with same style as seen in solid viewport?

Tags: rendering, workbench-render-engine

I'm new to Blender and I like very much the esthetics of the viewport. Is it possible to replicate those settings when rendering it?

[image]

I got this look when those settings are applied.

[image: solid view settings]

Bigger resolution image:
[image]

Comment: the Input > Ambient Occlusion (AO output) node and the Input > Geometry (Pointiness output) seem to be the closest thing to this cavity effect, but it looks like you can't render the exact same thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the render engine from **Cycles** or **Eevee** to **Workbench** in the **Render Properties** tab and play with the configurations:
[image]

also, this video show in details how to use Workbench:
[Introduction to Workbench Blender 2.8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tnDythbQCZM)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to render *exactly* what you see in the viewport, you can use : View Menu / Viewport Render Image.

Before doing that, it could be nice to deactivate some options in the Overlays and Gizmos settings. You can even uncheck the menu icons to disable them totally.

[image: Gizmos and Overlays settings]